# intellij idea, generating persistence mapping with relationships

Tags: sql-server-2008, jsf-2, intellij-idea, mapping, openjpa

i have my sql server database and i used "generate persistence mapping" in intellij to get my java classes, but the relationships defined on my sql server database were not mapped, it seems i can add them with the "add relationship" but i have a lot of tables with a lot of relationships so it is a pain in the ass to do it...

is there something that can map the database including the relationships? for example if i have a table user with a defined relationship of type one to many with a table potatoes, get a java class like this :

```
public class user{

private int iduser;
private String name;
private String password;

//relationship!!
private ArrayList<Potatoes>potatoes; //this is mapped like "private int id_potatoes" by intillij

public user(){}

//getters and setters

}
```

i´m using open JPA. amd i also can't find a way to auto generate DAO's with some basic methods (save, find, delete), i will have to code them myself!!! and im talking of atleast 40 tables!! it is ridiculous!!

i know there MUST be a way to do all this stuff automatically.   oh, im using jsf 2, i dont know if that is relevant to this question anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

when you generate persistence mapping, just **check** the below box option

> 匚 Show default relationships

by this to generate , you will get the table relationships you want. Hope to help you :)

[image]